# Magento2: Need to show system filed value in label not in input box

Tags: magento2

I need to show field value in the label, not in the input box.

[image]

Please suggest for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add label type field in your **system.xml** :

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<field id="expiry_date" translate="label" type="label" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
    <label>Expiry Date</label>
</field>
```

set label value in your **config.xml**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <section>
            <group>
                <expiry_date>Your values here</expiry_date>
            </group>
        </section>
    </default>
</config>
```

Output :

[image]

Flush cache and check output

Comment: Thanks! It works for me

Comment: Happy to help !! You can accept answer if it's helpful for you.

Answer (score 3):

you can add in app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<field id="test" translate="label" type="label" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
    <label>My Test lable</label>
</field>
```

in config.xml you can write

app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <section>
            <group>
                <test>My test value</test>
            </group>
        </section>
    </default>
</config>
```

so will get out put like this

> My Test lable         My test value

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You can add these lines in your `system.xml` file here in your custom module

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

You can add field like this..

```
<field id="label" translate="label" type="label" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
    <label>Test</label>
    <frontend_model>Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field\Label</frontend_model>
</field>
```

You need to create one Block file now here on this path in your custom module

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config/Form/Field/Label.php

Content for this file is..

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field;

class Label extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        if (!$this->getTemplate()) {
            $this->setTemplate('system/config/fieldset/custom_label.phtml');
        }

        return $this;
    }

    protected function _getElementHtml(\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement $element)
    {
        return $this->_toHtml();
    }
}
```

Now you finally need to create one template file in your custom module here on this path..

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/system/config/fieldset/custom_label.phtml

Content for this file is..

```
<label><?php echo __("Your label here"); ?></label>
```

Hope this will work for you!